# Removing/hiding the option to "safely remove USB devices" via GPO and registry

Tags: windows, usb, group-policy, windows-registry

I ave already gone through [How to prevent Windows from safely removing hardware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12833/how-to-prevent-windows-from-safely-removing-hardware) and it has a registry based solution for WinXP, however what I am after is:
1. a GPO based solution
2. windows 7, 2003 and 2008 as well

thanks

UPD: tried

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MYDEVICE] 
"DisableRemovable"=dword:00000001
```

doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried removing though GPO and other ways, apparently the driver itself simply blovks anything the registry sets. Spoken to the driver developer, and he's going to apply some changes. So there was no actual solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GPO Preferences to set this registry key.

You can look at [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092.aspx) for information on how to do this. Just make sure the computers have the Client Side Extensions installed and you should be ready to go.

Comment: tried it - it's the driver itself, it simply blocks the option no matter what I do